# How to control upload extension initiated from controller center?

Tags: ios, upload, replaykit

I implemented upload extension and setup RTMP server for broadcasting via upload extension. The broadcasting is initiated from control center, not through SetupUI extension. Since the SampleHandler.m doesn't provide RPBroadcastController, I can't programmatically pause or stop the broadcasting. I'd like to at least stop the broadcasting and show error message that the server is not available. I've looking through all WWDC docs, but couldn't find much info. Mobcrush is showing error message like "Not logged in", how they do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a mistakes in my code, `finishBroadcastWithError` function should call `[super finishBroadcastWithError:]` to call RPBroadcastController to stop broadcasting and show proper error message. You don't need to access `RPBroadcastController` nor need `SetupUI` to controller broadcast. That was it, I wasted 2 days on this, I wish no one do that.

Comment: How to pause the broadcast ?